# How to get values of properties having List<string> in it in C#?

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I have below class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<string> Products {get; set;}
}
```

if I use the below code, I am able to get value of '''Name''' property. However not able to get values of Products list.

How to do that?

```
Type type = user.GetType();
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties();
string str = "{";
foreach (var prop in props)
{
   str+= (prop.Name+":"+  prop.GetValue(user))+",";
}
return str.Remove(str.Length-1)+"}";
```

Comment: Find a json serializer that works for you. There are many on NuGet. What you're doing is the hard way.

Comment: `user` is an instance of `MyClass`?

Comment: I know people who do things like write their own serializers. They make everyone sad.

Comment: how about the result if you have a nested class property in your class `MyClass`?how the data will looks like for the list of string?`prop.GetValue(user)` will gives you just the type, like `"System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]"`

Comment: @Sajid Yes I am getting the same you mentioned, instead of "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]" I need proper values say "Product1" and "Product2" , How to achieve that?

Comment: @Gaurav123 `if (property.GetValue(user, null) is IList list)` and take each element for ``list`` inside if.

Comment: Please rephrase your question and explain what you are trying to do explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Add a `ToJson()` method to the type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<string> Products {get; set;}

    public string ToJson()
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder("{");
        result.Append("\"Name\":\"")
              .Append(Name)
              .Append("\",{\"Products\":[{\"Product\":\"");

        var delimiter = "";
        foreach(var product in Products)
        {
           result.Append(delimter).Append(product);
           delimiter = "\"},{\"Product\":\"";
        }
        result.Append("\"}]}");
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then the code becomes:

```
string str = user.ToJson();
```

If you need to do this for a number of different types, create an interface they can implement:

```
interface ICanHazJson
{
    string ToJson();
}
```

And then make each of the types you care about implement the interface:

```
public class MyClass : ICanHazJson
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<string> Products {get; set;}

    public string ToJson()
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder("{");
        result.Append("\"Name\":\"")
              .Append(Name)
              .Append("\",{\"Products\":[{\"Product\":\"");

        var delimiter = "";
        foreach(var product in Products)
        {
           result.Append(delimter).Append(product);
           delimiter = "\"},{\"Product\":\"";
        }
        result.Append("\"}]}");
        return result.ToString();
    }
}
```

And if there are *many* types where this matters, that's all the more reason to find a battle-tested json serializer on NuGet that will do what you need and not blow up on some unexpected edge case.

Comment: Thanks for response, actually I need generic solution.
I want to pass just a class name and that class can have n number of properties including string, int and List<string> properties.
Once I will pass class name I need to format properties name and their values but not to JSON

Comment: The format demonstrated in the question **IS** json.